# how transform single component props to Top Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image]

above picture, `<NavTop />` Component has `doLogout()`,

```
class NavTop extends Component{
    doLogout(){
        _user.logout().then((res) => {
            this.props.history.push('/login')
        })
    }
}
```

and then logout success, location not redirect "/login", but I get undefined,`this.props.history is undefined`.
if I use `this.props.history.push()` redirect "/login", how to resolve the "props" and gentle redirect "/login"?

now i use `window.location.href = '/login'`, I think this way is violence?
So have you other way? please help me! thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your component within the `withRouter` HOC to use the history property.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

class NavTop extends Component{
    doLogout(){
        _user.logout().then(() => this.props.history.push('/login'))
    }
}

export default withRouter(NavTop);
```